# Set end date to a max of 31 days

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to extract weeks from the given `Start Date` and `End Date`.

If the date range is more than 31 day's I need to restrict the endDate to max of 31 days.

**Example:**

```
Start date : 1st May 2018
default end date: 30th June 2018
New endDate should be: 31st May 2018
```

Below is my code to extract the weeks

```
weekByDates() {
  let dates = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pfsessionFilter'));
let stDate = moment((dates[0].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
let eDate = moment((dates[1].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

let startDate = moment(stDate);
let endDate = moment(eDate);
let weekData = [];
if(endDate.diff(startDate, 'days')>31)
endDate = moment(startDate.add(31, 'days')); 
while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
    if(weekData.length > 0) {
        // Update end date
        let lastObj = weekData[weekData.length - 1];
        lastObj['endDate'] =  moment(startDate).format('MM/DD');
        lastObj['label'] = `${lastObj.startDate} - ${lastObj['endDate']} (week${weekData.length})`
        startDate.add(1, 'days');
    }
    weekData.push({startDate: moment(startDate).format('MM/DD')});
    startDate.add(6, 'days');
}
if(startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
    // Update last object
    let lastObj = weekData[weekData.length - 1];
    lastObj['endDate'] =  moment(endDate).format('MM/DD');
    lastObj['label'] = `${lastObj.startDate} - ${lastObj['endDate']} (week${weekData.length})`
}
console.log(weekData)
return weekData;
}
```

Please help on how to restrict the endDate to 31 days from start date ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/6rU39T0vIPVQkFnydKbC?p=preview

Comment: why are you turning a moment, to a string and back to a moment? And what is the `while` loop for?

Comment: i've updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if range is greater than 31 days, than use add method as

```
weekByDates() 
{ 
  let dates = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getDates')); 
  let stDate = moment((dates[0].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
  let eDate = moment((dates[1].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
  let startDate = moment(stDate); 
  let endDate = moment(eDate); 
  if(eDate.diff(stDate, 'days')>31)
    endDate = moment(stDate).add(31, 'days'); 
  let weekData = [];      while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) 
{ .... }
```

Comment: Can you add console logs to it and check which part is not working specifically

Comment: add plunkar project

Comment: with you're code `{startDate: "02/19", endDate: "02/19", label: "02/19 - 02/19 (week1)"}` i'm getting only onw record which is wrong

Comment: Please check plukar

Comment: Now I edited that, you can check console logs to see result

Comment: `endDate = moment(startDate).add(31, 'days')` this line fixed it

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict the days using add() function,

```
weekByDates() {
  let dates = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getDates'));
  let stDate = moment((dates[0].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  let eDate = moment((dates[1].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  let startDate = moment(stDate);
  let endDate = moment(stDate.add(31, 'days'));
  let weekData = [];
  while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
    ....
}
```

Hope it hepls you.

Comment: OP need to set end date to 31 only if range is greater than 31 days, your solution will set end date to 31 even if range is lower than 31

Answer (score -1):

I use this judgment

```
if(endDate.diff(startDate, 'days') > 31){
//More than 31 days
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?